# How to retrieve more than a 100 tweets on twitter API V2 using python

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, twitterapi-python, twitter-api-v2

I upgraded my access to Basic, and I am allowed to retrieve 10,000 tweets per month. I am trying to scrape 3000 tweets for a particular key word, my code is attached, but i get an error that the max i can scrape is a 100. Is there a way to automate this so that I can reach my goal? Thank you very much for your help.

```
import tweepy
from textblob import TextBlob
from wordcloud import WordCloud
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys
import re

client = tweepy.Client(
    bearer_token=bearerToken,
    consumer_key=consumerKey,
    consumer_secret=consumerSecret,
    access_token=accessToken,
    access_token_secret=accessTokenSecret
)
response = client.search_recent_tweets(query='nurofen', max_results=3316)
print(response.meta)

tweets = response.data

nurofen_twts = pd.DataFrame([tweet.text for tweet in tweets], columns=['Tweets'])
```

I tried changing my code, but this time I was getting a 403 error that said I needed to upgrade my access level. The code is below:

```
# Authenticate with Twitter API
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumerKey, consumerSecret)
auth.set_access_token(accessToken, accessTokenSecret)

# Create API client
client = tweepy.API(auth)


# Define the function to clean the tweets
def clean_text(text):
    text = re.sub(r'@[A-Za-z0-9]+', '', text)  # Removes @mentions
    text = re.sub(r'#', '', text)
    text = re.sub(r'RT[\s]+', '', text)
    text = re.sub(r'https?:\/\/\S+', '', text)
    return text


# Variables
query = 'nurofen'
total_tweets = 3316
max_results = 100
tweets = []

# Fetch tweets
while len(tweets) < total_tweets:
    if total_tweets - len(tweets) < max_results:
        max_results = total_tweets - len(tweets)
    response = client.search_tweets(q=query, max_results=max_results)

    tweets.extend(response.data)
    if response.meta.next_token:
        next_token = response.meta.next_token
        response = client.search_tweets(q=query, max_results=max_results, next_token=next_token)
    else:
        break


# Create dataframe from tweets
nurofen_twts = pd.DataFrame([clean_text(tweet.text) for tweet in tweets], columns=['Tweets'])

print(nurofen_twts)
```

Comment: Before making any significant requests, I'd recommend storing your tweets in a JSON or something of the sort, so that if you modify your code, you won't have to fetch those tweets again, which could run your 10,000 tweet limit out. what I'd suggest is making a small API request (like 50 tweets) and test putting it in a JSON first, so that you know your code works. Then you can make the 3300-sized request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a loop:

```py
import math

num = 3316
num /= 100
# round to the nearest 100
# turns 3316 into 3400
# but won't turn 3300 into 3400
num = math.ceil(num) * 100
# inclusive
num += 1

tweets = []
until_id = None
for i in range(0, num, 100):
  response = client.search_recent_tweets(query='nurofen', max_results=100, until_id=until_id)
  # until_id
  print(response.meta)
  
  tweets_chunk = response.data
  
  tweets.extend(tweets_chunk)
  
  until_id = tweets_chunk[-1].id # or the other way how to get the last tweet ID from the list
```

It just requests 100 tweets, stores the last tweet ID, then requests another 100 tweets which were posted with a smaller ID than the stored ID, until it requests all the tweets you need.

It rounds it to the nearest 100 up, so if you have 3300 it will not do anything, but if you input 3301 it will round it up to 3400.

Comment: hi @Георгий Гришко thank you so much for your reply. This might be a stupid question  but please bear with me, I'm new to this. If I want to store the tweets in a dataframe, do I use the variable tweets_chunk or tweets?

Comment: @ChiomaAmuwa Use the "tweets" variable if you want to have all 3316 tweets in the dataframe

Comment: I ran your code but I got a type error for this line, `tweets.extend(tweets_chunk)`  The error says the 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: @ChiomaAmuwa according to your code, you are getting the tweets from `response.data`, so I'm not sure what's the reason. Try putting `print(tweets_chunk)` before the `tweets.extend` command to see if it has no more tweets left at some point.

Comment: Some tweets were printed out into the terminal but I noticed they were not in english and most of them were repeated. A total of 14 tweets were printed then the none type error was thrown again.

Comment: @ChiomaAmuwa I can't exactly say why most of them are repeated. However, to prevent `NoneType` errors, you can break out of the loop by checking if there's any tweets left: `if len(tweets_chunk) == 0: break` (after setting the tweets chunk value to response.data).

Comment: I will try to check what causes it to repeat tweets and edit my answer if I find out why.

Comment: do you know what I can do to retrieve only english tweets. I also got an type error that says object of type 'NoneType' has no len(). Onto good news, I was able to get more tweets this time, so thank you very much.

Comment: @ChiomaAmuwa I don't think Twitter has a way to only get tweets of a specific language. What about the `len()` error: you can try this: `if not tweets_chunk or len(tweets_chunk) == 0: break`, it makes sure to not call `len()`on `NoneType` objects